# Java: Delete and recreate object

Tags: java

I have a infinite loop where I create an object. At the end of the loop, after creating the object I run it. When running the object the program will block because I have another infinite loop in my TcpClient-object. But sometimes this infinite loop will break because of an handled error, and will call a specific method in my mTcpClient-Object called "reconnect". There I would like to delete the mTcpClient object, so that the first infinite loop will go on and create a new mTcpClient-object.

How can I do this?

```
while(true) {

    //we create a TCPClient object and
    mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
        @Override
        public void reconnect() {
            // HERE I want to delete this object
        }
    ....
   });

    if (mTcpClient != null)
        mTcpClient.run();
}
```

Comment: You can't manually `delete` an object in Java. Can you clarify what you mean by `deleting` the object?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show your full program, but as much I understand your question, you can't delete objects when you want. It is done automatically when the garbage collector will check for unused objects. If you want to do something while `TcpClient`'s garbage collection, you can override `protected void finalize()` method of `Object`.

Comment: @Ved Recommending finalizers is nearly always bad advice.

Comment: @texNewbie Its very likely that your overal design is flawed. Post more code.

Comment: @chrylis, True, using `protected void finalize()` is not good, and it _does not promise_ that the object would be garbage collected. But to free any resources loaded through native methods, using `finalize()` is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mTcpClient = null;` Setting an object to null will cause the garbage collector to delete the object for you.

Comment: What you are suggesting is not possible. `mTcpClient` won't be accessible within the anonymous inner class. Try it out.

Comment: I tried, I think this could work. But I have to check a few things until I know if this is the solution for my problem.